# What is the probability that a random chord in a sphere touches opposite hemispheres?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability

(**edited**) Consider the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and its upper $(z>0)$ and lower $(z<0)$ hemispheres.

Draw two independent, uniformly distributed points $X,Y$ on $\mathbb{S}^2$.
Given $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$, what is the probability that $X$ and $Y$ belong to different hemispheres among the above two, *conditioning* by the event that the chord $[X,Y]$ makes an angle $\theta$ with the $z$-axis?

Numerically I find that this probability is $\cos{\theta}$.

Could anyone help me justify this $\cos{\theta}$?

Comment: "consider a random chord which makes an angle $\theta$ with the $z$ axis". This definition of the probability space is too vague to allow for any more meaningful answer than "something between $0$ and $1$"). Also, I suspect that MSE is a more appropriate place for this question unless your probability distribution is very fancy.

Comment: Can you describe your numerical work in detail?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. As written, the distribution does not depend on $\theta$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : As I understand it, the question is whether the conditional probability that the random chord touches both hemispheres given that the chord makes an angle $\theta$ with the $z$ axis is $\cos\theta$.

Comment: @Iosif: I generate random gaussian 3D vectors, which after normalisation are uniformly distributed on a sphere. Then I randomly pick two of them, and from their coordinates I check if they belong to opposite or same hemispheres, and what angle the corresponding chord makes with the z axis. I repeat the operation and do statistics on the results, and that's what I find.

Comment: @Emil: The probability does depend on $\theta$, imagine two extreme cases: If $\theta$ is zero (the chord is vertical) it necessarily has to touch both hemispheres. If $\theta$ is $\pi/2$ (the chord is horizontal) it can only start and end on one same hemisphere.

Comment: @user655870 : By "generate", do you mean "simulate", i.e., "get corresponding pseudo-random numbers"?

Comment: @Iosif: Yes indeed...

Comment: @user655870 : You estimate the conditional probability (given an event of probability $0$) by the ratio $r=num/den$ of two small probabilities, $num$ and $den$. Each of these two probabilities is an integral over a comparatively small region in the huge 6D space. Therefore, I think it is very hard to estimate $num$ and $den$ accurately enough by simulation. So, I doubt that such simulation can be reliable enough.

Comment: I took the liberty to integrate the edit to the question itself. It should be clearer this way, but I might have been heavy-handed so let me know if you prefer me to reverse part or all of the edit.

Comment: @Benoît It's very good this way thank you.

Comment: What do you do if the chord is skew to the z-axis?  Gerhard "Not Sure Of The Condition" Paseman, 2020.07.28.

Comment: With the new formulation it is, indeed, true. The straightforward computation results in the integral $\frac 2\pi\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\frac {d\alpha}{1+\tan^2\theta\cos^2\alpha}$, which is elementary but somewhat unpleasant to compute (the usual trig substitution $z=\tan\alpha$). However such a simple answer should have an equally simple explanation, so I'd rather wait for someone to find a "no pen or paper solution"

Comment: Could you explain how you obtain this integral?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a true "no pen or paper" solution requested by fedja, but at least it avoids integrals. :-)

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random vectors on the unit sphere. Write $E = (X - Y) / |X - Y|$ for the unit vector parallel to the chord $XY$, and $Z = \tfrac{1}{2} (X + Y)$.

[image: notation]

**Claim:** Conditionally on $E = e$, the projection $Z = \tfrac{1}{2}(X + Y)$ of the chord $XY$ onto its perpendicular bisector plane $\pi_e = \{v : v \perp e\}$ (the entire chord projects onto a single point) is uniformly distributed over the unit disk in $\pi_e$.

Given the above claim, the proof is straightforward. Indeed: given any unit vector $e$ such that $\theta = \arcsin |e \cdot (0,0,1)|$ as in the question, and conditionally on $E = e$, $X$ and $Y$ belong to different hemispheres if and only if $Z$ belongs to an ellipse, which is the projection of the equator of the unit sphere onto $\pi_e$. This ellipse has semi-axes $1$ and $\cos \theta$ (this becomes pretty clear if one draws a picture). The area of this ellipse is equal to $\cos \theta$ times the area of the unit disk, and the desired result follows. Thus, it remains to prove the claim.

[image: projection]

*Proof of the claim:* Since the random variable $X \cdot Y$ is uniformly distributed over $[-1, 1]$ (Archimedes's theorem!), the random variable
$$ \|Z\|^2 = \|\tfrac{1}{2} (X + Y)\|^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} (1 - X \cdot Y) $$
is uniformly distributed over $[0, 1]$. By rotational symmetry, $\|Z\|^2$ and $E$ are independent. It follows that conditionally on $E = e$, $\|Z\|^2$ is uniformly distributed over $[0, 1]$. Again by symmetry, the conditional distribution of $Z$ (given $E = e$) is invariant under rotations of $\pi_e$, and so it follows that this conditional distribution is uniform over the unit disk on $\pi_e$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz, there are many things I don't get: 
- What do you exactly mean by "the projection Z of the chord XY"? I get what projecting a point or a vector means, but a chord? If it's the same Z as defined before, then I would say that is the middle of the chord, is it not? 
- I'm not sure what plane $\pi_e$ you're talking about, there's an infinity perpendicular to e, do you implicitly mean the one passing by the origin? 
- Shouldn't it be arccos and not arcsin?

Comment: @user655870: Since $e$ is parallel to the chord $XY$, the plane $\pi_e$ is perpendicular to it, and hence the entire chord projects onto a single point $Z$. And indeed $Z = \tfrac{1}{2} (X + Y)$: since $|X| = |Y| = 1$, the line passing through the origin and the midpoint $\tfrac{1}{2} (X + Y)$ of $XY$ is perpendicular to $XY$, and hence it lies in the plane $\pi_e$. I'll try to add some pictures to my answer in a few minutes. And please do ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and pictures! Now I see. I'm still puzzled about how you define your $\theta$, in my case it's the one formed with the z axis (perp to the equatorial plane), did I miss something basic again?

Comment: I remember going in the direction of your claim in the following way: Imagine you distribute random points on the surface of the sphere with uniform density, then you link them by pairs in a given direction so as to make all possible parallel chords in that given direction. Then I thought the $\cos{\theta}$ would be obvious if the density of chords crossing $\pi_e$ was uniform across $\pi_e$, but I thought it couldn't be uniform, because on the edge for example, isn't it infinite?

Comment: I'm trying to reconcile your claim with my intuition, when I look at a (transparent) spherical shell, the density of protected matter is infinite on the edge. So there should be an infinite density of chords there, no? I can't picture how it can be uniform.

Comment: @user655870: This is the fun part! If one projects $X$ onto a fixed plane, then indeed the distribution concentrates near the boundary. More precisely, the density function is proportional to $1/sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. However, here we project on a random hyperplane $\pi_E$, and condition on the event $E = e$. This conditioning changes the distribution: given that $E = e$, the random variable $X$ is no longer uniformly distributed over the unit sphere! The "algebraic" argument used in the "proof of the claim" is not very intuitive, so here is a way to imagine that. (1/2)

Comment: Suppose that we condition on $E$ being very close to $e = (0,0,1)$ (rather than exactly equal to $e$). If $X$ is fixed, then $Y$ is necessarily in a very narrow, vertically aligned cone with an apex at $X$. The probability of this event is the surface area of the intersection of the sphere and the cone, and it depends on $X$: if $X$ is close to the pole, the intersection will be large, while if $X$ is near the equator, then the intersection can get very small. (2/2)